# How do I keep from focusing the last EditText when navigating from a tabbed Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-viewpager, android-navigation

I have 3 tabs in a ViewPager. Focus in Tab 2 is in the first EditText by default. When I navigate from Tab 2 to Tab 3 and back, I find that focus is in the *last* EditText of Tab 2. If I then go to Tab 1 and back, focus is back in the first EditText. So it seems that when I navigate "to the right," focus is going to the last EditText of the fragment I was on. I don't want this. I want focus to be either where I left it or where it is by default.

*Further*, I don't want to simply bring focus back to the first EditText upon returning because it going to the last EditText in the first place scrolls my page down. I want it scrolled up with focus back in my EditText.

Is there a way to prevent focus from going to the last EditText in Tab 2 when I swipe to Tab 3?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this is an old post, but for the benefit of others who may be looking.
I was able to get rid of this issue by putting android:focusable="false" on the last editText.